# SQL Server 2000 Connection Error - Pre-Login Handshake?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sql-server-2000

I am developing an ASP.NET application in VS 2010 with a SQL Server 2000 backend (I know, I know . . .)

I have been working just fine with this setup for the greater part of the last 3 months. However, yesterday I did apply VS 2010 SP1 and now connecting to this database causes the following error:

> Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while
>   attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This
>   could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was
>   unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting
>   to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=72;
>   handshake=44924

Keep in mind that I have made NO changes to either the connection string or the SQL Server 2000 server/database. So there must be a reason why it's happening since the new additions.

My connection items are fairly vanilla with

```
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = sqlStatement;
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
resultData.Load(dr);
dr.Close();
conn.Close();
```

And my connection string looks like

```
Data Source=192.168.1.200;Persist Security Info=false;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User Id=MyUser;Password=MyPW;Timeout=45;
```

You can see that I made changes to the timeout but this didn't work. But, again, I shouldn't have to make any changes. I just applied the VS 2010 SP 1 yesterday, that has been the only change. HELP!

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/#comment-82996) ?

Comment: Great suggestion. The answer must be something along these lines - it must be a local client change that is causing this. However, I did make those changes and it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Refer  below link 

http://serverfault.com/questions/423013/sql-an-error-occurred-during-the-pre-login-handshake/423087

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed this by opening up port 1433 (SQL) on the server firewall.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue that you have. I solved this issue by allowing connections between the SQL client and SQL host in the firewall. And absolutely, you can grant port 1433 access, which is specifically used for SQL Server.